# Writing in different columns with opencsv

Tags: java

I am using Opencsv and I'd like to write Strings, each one should be in a column.
I am trying to do it with CSVWriter but I can't see a method for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [project page](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) you can find some examples.

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"), ','); 
// feed in your array (or convert your data to an array) 
String[] entries = new String[] {"first","second","third"};
writer.writeNext(entries);   
writer.close();
```

Each element in the array will be put into a column on the csv file.